# why do python and BS4 return only one 'href' when called specifically, but all values when called as text?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Scraping a page and trying to get all the urls from the first column. When I call as text I get everything in the div, which I get. But, when I specifically target the URL, I only get the first one. How do I get all of them - separated for storage?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen 
base_url = "http://www.heavyliftpfi.com/news/"
html = urlopen(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read().decode('latin-1', 'ignore'),"lxml")
main_div = soup.select_one("div.fullWidth")
div_sub = main_div.select_one("div.leftcol")
print (div_sub).text # I get that this gets everything as .text
print (div_sub).h2.a['href'] # alternate - with only one 'href' return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are navigating the parse tree via tag names, if you have multiple matching attribute names, **only the first one is returned**.  This is expected behavior.  Try using **`find_all()`** to search for them instead.

from the BS4 docs:

> "Using a tag name as an attribute will give you only the first tag by
>   that name."
>
> "If you need to get all the  tags, or anything more complicated
>   than the first tag with a certain name, you’ll need to use one of the
>   methods described in Searching the tree, such as *find_all()*"

see: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names

Answer (score 0):

It was the findAll, but I needed to move up the tree

```
for a in main_div.findAll('a', href=True):
    print a['href']
```